# asp.net | values sent trough ajax received as null in handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to send the 'file' attachment to handler(and send it with email)

This is the code I am using to send it to handler(JS)

When I debug it I see the right values including the file(debug in java-script).

```
function sendCv_click() {    
var settings = {
    'data': getData("sendCv"),
    'url': "Handlers/SendCV.ashx",
    'contentType': 'false',
    'processData': 'false'
};
sendCV(settings);
};

function getData(){
     data = {
            'fullName': $('#txt_sendCv_fullName').val(),
            'cvFile':$('#fu_sendCv_upload')[0].files[0],
            'email': $('#txt_sendCv_email').val(),
            'checkBox': $('#sendCv_chkBox:checked').length
}

function sendCV(settings) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: settings.contentType,
            processData: settings.processData, 
            data: settings.data,
            url: settings.url,
            dataType: "json",
           success: function(data) {
                ...
            },
            error: function(data, xhr) {
               ...
           });
        }).always(function() {
            ...
        });       
    }
}
```

How can I get them in the handler page?

like that I get them as Null, why?

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{      
    string fullName = context.Request.Form.Get("fullName"); //It's Null
    string email = context.Request.Form.Get("email");//It's Null
    string chkBox_ad = context.Request.Form.Get("checkBox");  //It's Null
    /////how can i get the file here ??

    bool mailSent = Mail.SendCV(fullName, email, chkBox_ad);
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

    if (mailSent)
    {
        context.Response.Write("true");
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.Write("false");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work...

```
var postedFile = context.Request.Files[0];
```

Comment: thanks but it only partially answer my question.
as I wrote, if I put a break point in the handler.ashx, it's never hit.
what can be the reason?

Comment: Oh, sorry. How are you mapping the url (Handlers/SendCV.ashx) to the handler (handler.ashx)? Are you using the system.web.urlMappings element of the the web config?

Comment: it's OK:) this is how I map- "Handlers/SendCV.ashx" and if I change the 'contentType' and the 'processData' it is working.

Comment: so, how can i send the file to the 'handler'?

Comment: let me be more accurate I actually get in handler.ashx but i get all values as null- I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var parser = new MultipartParser(context.Request.InputStream);
if (parser.Success) {
  byte[] content = parser.FileContents;
  string filename = parser.Filename;
}
```

MultipartParser is opensource class - see http://multipartparser.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MultipartParser.cs